# Header navigation position

Tags: html, css, navigation, header

So, I've been doing a project for my school and i've came up with idea of fitness (not important). I set up logo and when i started the actual navigation I.. idk.. so i want my navigation to be aligned on the right side but all i tried didnt change position. anyone help ?
Here's the actual code

**HTML**

```
        <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/fit-logo.png" alt="logo" width="120" height="120">
        </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-about-us.html">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-news.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}

::selection {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.flex {
    display:flex;
}

.logo {
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    margin: 0 110px;
    float:left;
}

nav {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: You're not using the class of `flex` anywhere.

Comment: I know, i've created for future use. But first of all i wanted to align navigation right ?

Comment: If you don't use flexbox the properties you're applying to the `nav` mean nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you need to navigation like this. right?
[image]

For that, you need to have an idea about flexbox. You can refer this article for basic flexbox knowledge.

[CSS Flexbox from W3Schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

And this is the code for your navigation.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="logo"> <img src="./img/fit-logo.png" alt="logo" width="120" height="120"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index-about-us.html">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="index-trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
      <li><a href="index-news.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="index-contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  background-color: #1F1D36;
}

.logo{
  flex:1;
}

li{
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Poppins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation item to display inline.

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}

::selection {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.flex {
    display:flex;
}

.logo {
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}

nav {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul li {
      display: inline;
      padding:10px;
      float:right
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/fit-logo.png" alt="logo" width="120" height="120">
        </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-about-us.html">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-news.html">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
```